# How can i symbolize a map dynamically by data stored in mysql database in many tables (these tables have relationship through Primary Key and FK)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geoext, mysql

How can i symbolize a map dynamically by data stored in mysql database in many tables (these tables have relationship through Primary Key and FK). For instance "Disease Name"(chosen from drop down then "Affected Number" (from another drop down) "Sex" (to chosen from another drop down) then "Year" from another drop down box, after all an ok button to be hit to produce intended map. I am using geoserver 2.2  postgresql( postgis). I am try to outline the process but ended in smoke (my first design and so so), would any one ,as samaritan ,help me, plz. Thanks in advance.

my project is as in https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1NvUoakjNxwZ0VGSm15bE9fNkE

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to change the symbology (i.e.: use blue for men and pink for women) an option is using variable substitutions in SLDs as described in the [Geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html).

The idea is that you should be able to customize the rendering by passing additional custom params to the GetMap requests (with the [OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.mergeNewParams](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.mergeNewParams) function).

If variable substitution is not powerful enough than you could use [one of the dynamic SLD options](http://geo-solutions.blogspot.it/2012/04/dynamic-wms-styling-with-geoserver-sld.html) available with Geoserver.

If you only need to filter the dataset depending on user selection you can use [CQL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) filters instead.

Comment: Sir actually i am not getting route what to go along, because i have many (at least 500 table  connected by PK and Fk) in my sql again i have developed base map in postgis.Now how can i make a thematic layer as uDig does based on attribute(this attribute to be supplied ) by user form  input(multiple drop down boxes). U may look the model https://rapidshare.com/files/3556888089/UI%20design%20description.docx

Comment: @msi_g: instead of linking the doc from rapidshare I suggest you pull relevant details from the doc into the question so that it is more clear as to what you are trying to achieve. I cowardly refuse to open docx documents to answer a question here on GIS.SE ;-)

Comment: the link for my project is https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1NvUoakjNxwZ0VGSm15bE9fNkE